# How to generate multiple Bitcoin addresses from 1 public key?

Tags: java, hash, bitcoin, bitcoinj

I'm facing an issue regarding generation of Bitcoin addresses.

I've `public key`:

```
String xpub"xpub661MyMwAqRbcGJxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

I want to generate multiple `addresses` from `xpub`.

I'm using `bitcoinJ` library.

```
ECKey key=ECKey.fromPublicOnly(Base58.decode(xpub));
```

It throws exception of:

> Incorrect length for uncompressed encoding

I've read many articles, I found that `Ripemd160(SHA256(string));`.
After `hashing`, I `encode` in `Base58`, but couldn't achieve multiple addresses.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if my answer is the right one because I don't know how the BitcoinJ library works but just for info:

The bitcoin public key is kind of different from RSA public keys, you should add `04` at the beginning of the string.

In your case the key value should be equals to:

**04**xpub661MyMwAqRbcGJxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

So the public key generated will have the following:

*1 byte 0x04* + *65 bytes*: 32 bytes corresponding to X coordinate and 32 bytes corresponding to Y coordinate

Check:

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_version_1_Bitcoin_addresses
https://en.bitcoin.it/w/images/en/9/9b/PubKeyToAddr.png

To test/validate your address you can use this site:

http://gobittest.appspot.com/Address

Good luck

Comment: Yes, I agree with this answer

Comment: I followed this but without adding 04 at the start.
try again with your. hope it will generate valid address
but still confused about multiple addresses

Comment: `MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
       
 String hash=Base58.encode(digest.digest(xpub.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));`
trying this accroding to picture

Comment: What about the `Ripemd160`? As I see you've just hashed it with SHA256 then with Base58. @MuhammadSaad

Comment: `MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        String ripe=Base58.encode(ripemd160.getHash(digest.digest(xpub.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));
System.out.println("RIPE"+ ripe);`
but its not returning valid address

Comment: Humm, that's really sad! =( I don't know if you complete the process like mentioned in the image.

After the ripemd160 hashing try:
- Adding network bytes to the result (`result1`)
- Double hashing `result1` using SHA256 (`result2`)
- Taking first four bytes of `result2` and add it to `result1` (`result3`)
- Finally encode using Base58 result3

And good luck ^^